# ARRAYFORMULA ON SPECIFIC CELLS

Tags: sum, cell, addition, spreadsheet

So I have this formula, it basiclly mulitiplies every value in a row for every row and sums up the products, and while thats awesome and all

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(A1:A*B1:B*C1:C)))
```

I would like if there was a way to choose what rows it multiplies and sums up, if I can put a  specific letter or like tag those cells in any way and like "filter" them out so it only sums up lets say row 1,2,4 and so on and for infinity, how ever many rows Ill like to add and whichever rows I want to include!

```
EXAMPLE:
1: 100 4 10
2: 120 2 12
3: 125 5 10
4: 105 3 15
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand the question but I believe you could solve the problem by introducing a fourth column, using "1" to indicate rows to add to the sum and "0" for rows to ignore. By extending your formula to include the new column D each row is multiplied with 1 (adding the value, since N*1=N) or 0 (ignoring the value, since N*0=0):

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(iferror(A1:A*B1:B*C1:C*D1:D)))
```

The below example data would sum row 1, 2 and 4:

```
1: 100 4 10 1
2: 120 2 12 1
3: 125 5 10 0
4: 105 3 15 1
```